# How to have VBA select a button on a userform within another workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, userform, commandbutton, before-save

So I am creating thousands of workbooks using a VBA from a Master Workbook. I have a template the Vba pastes to. This template workbook has a VBA

```
BeforeSave
```

function where the user has to fill out a Userform to log changes the user decided to make durring that session.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("EDITS")
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")
Dim newrow As ListRow
Set newrow = tbl.ListRows.Add

SavePrompt.Show

With newrow
    .Range(1) = Now
    .Range(2) = SavePrompt.TextBox1.Text
End With

End Sub
```

My problem now is that the VBA I run is in the master workbook. (just to be clear) it opens the template, Copies Row5 from Master Workbook and Pastes to Row4 on Sheet 2 on Template Workbook, then saves..

```
wkbDest.SaveAs Filename:=Path & FileName2 & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

Here's the Problem because the BeforeSave VBA runs, opening a Userform. How can I have this Master VBA select the CommandButton1 on the Userform that is now open and pausing the Macro?

then closes..

```
wkbDest.Close
```

Comment: Maybe it's better to disable events instead.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my comment I suggest to disable events before you save

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
wkbDest.SaveAs Filename:=Path & FileName2 & ".xlsm", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

And the code triggered by BeforeSave event will not run.

Comment: Even though this doesn't answer my direct question. It solved my problem. thankyou